# How to watch class object values inside `useEffect`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Token from "./Token";

export default function App() {
  const tokenizerRef = useRef(new Token());

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("current token index: ", tokenizerRef.current.currentIndex);
  }, [tokenizerRef.current.currentIndex]);

  return <button onClick={tokenizerRef.current.advance}>Next</button>;
}
```

Token.js

```
class Token {
  constructor() {
    this.currentIndex = -1;
  }

  advance() {
    this.currentIndex++;
  }
}

export default Token;
```

I've a Token object ref inside `App.js`, and would like to watch the object field values(for this case when `currentTokenIndex` changes).

Currently clicking `Next` button, doesn't trigger the `useEffect`.

A better way of doing this, pointing to the right direction, will be appreciated.

Comment: refs, by their very nature, don't trigger re-renders when they change. That's the point of a ref. If there's something that directly affects rendering it should be in state, not a ref

Comment: Create a context then assign some values from this context to your component, for example a button. Set useEffect to trigger when the context changes. Inside useEffect you may see the object field values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use observer/subscriber pattern, specifically [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/) for this purpose.

Token.js

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

class Token {
  constructor() {
    this.currentIndex = -1;
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  advance() {
    this.currentIndex++;
  }
}

export default Token;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

const App = observer(({ tokenizer }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('current index changed: ', tokenizer.currentIndex)
  }, [tokenizer.currentIndex])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{tokenizer.currentIndex}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => tokenizer.advance()}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";
import Token from "./Token";

const tokenizer = new Token();

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App tokenizer={tokenizer} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```